# How to resize an uploaded image based on the longest side?

Tags: 6, media

I can't seem to figure out how get ImageCache to resize an image based on the longest side.

Desired behaviour:

```
upload image 800x532 --> resize image to 400x266 (landscape)
upload image 532x800 --> resize image to 266x400 (portrait)
```

Is this possible with ImageCache? If not, how can I achieve this? Aspect ratio must be preserved.

Comment: instead of answering your question with a comment, post an answer and mark it accepted once the allotted time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on this question; [ImageCache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) now offers a feature called Aspect Switcher which allows for different image styles based on the original images aspect ratio, if it's portrait or landscape.